# Find out which maven depedency a class belongs to

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Is there any way to find out in which a dependency a particular class is defined in IDEA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use usually step into the unknown file and see (at least partially) its' code.
If you press <kbd>Alt + F1</kbd> the project manager tab will be scrolled to the file in it's original jar.

See for example what happens if I do it for some Jetty class
[image: IJ Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Not in IDEA but on the Internet: Use `fc:` + fully qualified name on http://search.maven.org/

For example: `fc:org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Aorg.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils